# Contact Builder Marketing Cloud Connect Issues

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

does anyone have knowledge on how marketing cloud connect syncs data across CRM & MC ? If there is a scenario where a lead needs to enter via landing page, what would be ideal recommendation to have it enter into MC first or CRM first ? so far what I see is, contact builder does not provide what is being portrayed or may be my instance is not showing all the options it needs to. Like I have finished data designer linking DEs with primary keys but I don't see option where I can see all the contacts linked to each other using linked DEs.Plus there is not much documentation around it.  Can you keep same unique id across CRM & MC during lead generation & conversion into accounts ?

Answer (score 0):

Once Marketing Cloud Connect is set up between your SF Org and Marketing Cloud, the data is synced over at a defined interval (15, 30, 60 minutes). This pulls SF data into a synchronized data extension, which then needs to be transferred into sendable Marketing Cloud data extension using query activities or filters. Then the data can be used and segmented to subscribers.

It depends on your use case. Do you have dev resources at your disposal? Is there a requirement to house your lead data in SF?

If the requirement is to insert/update lead data into SF first, you would need a dev resource to create AMPscript and java to call the SF object and field(s) from what the lead submits on the page, and pass over to Salesforce. The fields would be inserted/updated on the object and synced to Marketing Cloud.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createsalesforceobject.htm